# Dalvik reengineering , structure of .dex files

Tags: android, reverse-engineering, dalvik

I'm trying to analyse compiled Dalvik code, but I found a problem. Here is a [specification](http://source.android.com/tech/dalvik/dex-format.html) of .dex format. I can get header of the file, but I couldn't understand what is going on next - when I use dexdump I have classes right next to header:

```
class_defs_off      : 61836 (0x00f18c)
data_size           : 368612
data_off            : 72312 (0x011a78)
Class #0 header:
class_idx           : 62
access_flags        : 1536 (0x0600)
```

But when I look at my bytecode there is something other. I can't understand what going next to header. According to specification it is `string_idi's`, but I'm not sure. What is the real structure of .dex files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The spec you refer to does in fact accurately portray how dex files are structured. (Note: I wrote that document.)

Dexdump doesn't output the full contents of a dex file in order, which explains some of your confusion. The `dx` tool can output an annotated listing of dex file contents when it generates a dex file. You might find this useful. Sorry, I don't remember the options offhand, but it'll be something like `--dex --dump-to=file.txt --dump-bytes`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Baksmali can dump the contexts of an existing dex file, in a format similar to the hex dump of dx. (The advantage is that it can dump an existing dex file)

`baksmali classes.dex -D out.dump`

Comment: Ah yeah, I should've known that baksmali had an option for that.

Comment: BTW, doesn't `dx` know how to read dex files too, these days? If so, it may be able to dump an existing dex file (or at least nearly so).

Comment: Hmm, yeah. I think support for reading was added for the dex file merge stuff, although it doesn't look like it can dump an existing dex file (yet). That would be a nice feature to have though, I'll have to look into it :)